# OpenSSH server default configuration options

Tags: ssh, openssh

OpenSSH server is configured by using sshd_config. I know there are defaults for nearly all options available and they are listed here (http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config).

I know, that some defaults changed through different ssh versions and a colleauge of mine added that even the same ssh versions between different Unix flavours use different default values.

Is there an overview available which version/OS/... uses which default values?

Comment: No.                      Why would you need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/sbin/sshd -tT` enables test mode and extended test mode. This command dumps a normalized output of what settings are going to be set and to which values.

I use the `-tT` first, and use the captured output as the starting point of all my configs.  This way I know exactly and explicitly what is going on with this particular release/build of OpenSSH.  It's annoying to do it for every release, but it's the only way I found to get the real values.

I used to parse out the manpage, but that turned out to be lagging behind the settings in the code.